# Passing multiple parameters to function variables in Powershell

Tags: function, powershell, parameters, parameter-passing

I have an issue I can't figure out. It is a syntax problem that can't solve. Let's say I have this function:

```
function putStudentCourse ($userName, $courseId)
{           
    $url = "http://myurl/learn/api/public/v1/courses/courseId:" + $courseId + "/users/userName:" + $userName

    $contentType = "application/json"       
    $basicAuth = post_token
    $headers = @{
              Authorization = $basicAuth
             }
    $body = @{
              grant_type = 'client_credentials'
             }
    $data = @{
            courseId = $courseId
            availability = @{
                available = 'Yes'
                }
            courseRoleId = 'Student'
        }
    $json = $data | ConvertTo-Json

    $putStudent = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Put -Uri $url -ContentType $contentType -Headers $headers -Body $json

    return $json
}
```

And then my main method:

```
#MAIN

$userName = "user02";
$courseId = "CourseTest101"

$output =  putStudentCourse($userName, $courseId)
Write-Output $output
```

Right now it is just returning the first vale ($userName) but the output shows like this:

```
{
    "availability":  {
                         "available":  "Yes"
                     },
    "courseRoleId":  "Student",
    "courseId":  null
}
```

Somehow $courseId is never filled and I am not sure why. What am I doing wrong?
Any help will be appreciated it.

Comment: Additional note: if you [use strict mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/set-strictmode), it will catch this incorrect function call usage.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's a syntax issue.  When defining a function, you put the parameters in parenthesis as you correctly did here:

```
function putStudentCourse ($userName, $courseId)
```

But when you *invoke* a function, you do **not** put the arguments in parenthesis.  Change your code to read like this:

```
$output =  putStudentCourse $userName $courseId
```

The powershell interpreter interprets the original code

```
$output =  putStudentCourse($userName, $courseId)
```

To mean, "create a list of ($userName, $courseId), and pass that as the first parameter to putStudentCourse."

Comment: Thank you very much, that did it!